# React.Js and Video.js integration

Tags: reactjs, video.js

Following below article i am trying to show the videos in my react application.

[reactjsvideojs](https://docs.videojs.com/tutorial-react.html)
But videos are not getting updated when i render video component dynamically.

```
RenderVideo(path){
const videoJsOptions = {
autoplay: true,
controls: true,
sources: [{
src: path,
type: 'video/mp4'
}]
}

return <VideoPlayer { ...videoJsOptions } />
}
```

Calling when i click on the video thumbnails.

```
 {props.imgs[index].mediaType === 'VIDEO' && (
      <div className={styles.videoContainer}> 
             {RenderVideo(props.imgs[index].primaryLink)}
      </div>
    )}
```

VideoJsplayer component

```
class VideoJsPlayer extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { onReady, ...options } = this.props;
    this.player = videojs(this.videoNode, options, onReady);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.player) {
      this.player.dispose();
    }
  }

  render() {
    /* eslint-disable jsx-a11y/media-has-caption */
    return (
      <div data-vjs-player>
        <video
          ref={node => (this.videoNode = node)}
          className="video-js vjs-big-play-centered"
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

VideoJsPlayer.propTypes = {
  onReady: PropTypes.func,
};

VideoJsPlayer.defaultProps = {
  onReady: noop,
};

export default VideoJsPlayer
```

Can someone please help me why the videos are not getting updated dynamically.

Here are the things i observed 
1) Second when i rendervideo it's not hitting componentdidmount.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a react component [react-video-js-player](https://github.com/karan101292/react-video-js-player) which uses videoJS internally and exposes all of videoJS APIs. It will give you videojs instance so that you can integrate various videojs plugins too.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import VideoPlayer from 'react-video-js-player';

class VideoApp extends Component {
    player = {}
    state = {
        video: {
            src: "http://www.example.com/path/to/video.mp4",
            poster: "http://www.example.com/path/to/video_poster.jpg"
        }
    }

    onPlayerReady(player){
        console.log("Player is ready: ", player);
        this.player = player;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <VideoPlayer
                    src={this.state.video.src}
                    poster={this.state.video.poster}
                    onReady={this.onPlayerReady.bind(this)}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default VideoApp;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're initiating the video options in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method which will only be triggered once when you mount the component for the first time only not in future updates of the component. So most likely the first video render is working fine but not the next ones, right?

I think you should place what is inside `componentDidMount` into another lifecycle method that will be triggered each time the props are changed, something like `componentWillReceiveProps` or `componentWillUpdate`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i tried both but it did not work.